# Parallax slider

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I have used a parallax script from this tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/01/03/parallax-slider/

I have posted a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rob475/ZTRAc/3/

I just need to know how I can place the buildings in the gaps. The distance between the hyperlinked buildings are varied.

Is this possible to do with the script I am using?

Any advice or tips would be most appreciated

```
            (function($) {
            $.fn.parallaxSlider = function(options) {
                var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.parallaxSlider.defaults, options);
                return this.each(function() {
                    var $pxs_container  = $(this),
                    o               = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $pxs_container.data()) : opts;

                    //the main slider
                    var $pxs_slider     = $('.pxs_slider',$pxs_container),
                    //the elements in the slider
                    $elems          = $pxs_slider.children(),
                    //total number of elements
                    total_elems     = $elems.length,
                    //the navigation buttons
                    $pxs_next       = $('.pxs_next',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_prev       = $('.pxs_prev',$pxs_container),
                    //the bg images
                    $pxs_bg1        = $('.pxs_bg1',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_bg2        = $('.pxs_bg2',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_bg3        = $('.pxs_bg3',$pxs_container),
                    //current image
                    current         = 0,
                    //the thumbs container
                    $pxs_thumbnails = $('.pxs_thumbnails',$pxs_container),
                    //the thumbs
                    $thumbs         = $pxs_thumbnails.children(),
                    //the interval for the autoplay mode
                    slideshow,
                    //the loading image
                    $pxs_loading    = $('.pxs_loading',$pxs_container),
                    $pxs_slider_wrapper = $('.pxs_slider_wrapper',$pxs_container);

                    //first preload all the images
                    var loaded      = 0,
                    $images     = $pxs_slider_wrapper.find('img');

                    $images.each(function(){
                        var $img    = $(this);
                        $('<img/>').load(function(){
                            ++loaded;
                            if(loaded   == total_elems*2){
                                $pxs_loading.hide();
                                $pxs_slider_wrapper.show();

                                //one images width (assuming all images have the same sizes)
                                var one_image_w     = $pxs_slider.find('img:first').width();

                                /*
                                need to set width of the slider,
                                of each one of its elements, and of the
                                navigation buttons
                                 */
                                setWidths($pxs_slider,
                                $elems,
                                total_elems,
                                $pxs_bg1,
                                $pxs_bg2,
                                $pxs_bg3,
                                one_image_w,
                                $pxs_next,
                                $pxs_prev);

                                /*
                                    set the width of the thumbs
                                    and spread them evenly
                                 */
                                $pxs_thumbnails.css({
                                    'width'         : one_image_w + 'px',
                                    'margin-left'   : -one_image_w/2 + 'px'
                                });
                                var spaces  = one_image_w/(total_elems+1);
                                $thumbs.each(function(i){
                                    var $this   = $(this);
                                    var left    = spaces*(i+1) - $this.width()/2;
                                    $this.css('left',left+'px');

                                    if(o.thumbRotation){
                                        var angle   = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
                                        $this.css({
                                            '-moz-transform'    : 'rotate('+ angle +'deg)',
                                            '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ angle +'deg)',
                                            'transform'         : 'rotate('+ angle +'deg)'
                                        });
                                    }
                                    //hovering the thumbs animates them up and down
                                    $this.bind('mouseenter',function(){
                                        $(this).stop().animate({top:'-10px'},100);
                                    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                                        $(this).stop().animate({top:'0px'},100);
                                    });
                                });

                                //make the first thumb be selected
                                highlight($thumbs.eq(0));

                                //slide when clicking the navigation buttons
                                $pxs_next.bind('click',function(){
                                    ++current;
                                    if(current >= total_elems)
                                        if(o.circular)
                                            current = 0;
                                    else{
                                        --current;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    highlight($thumbs.eq(current));
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg3,
                                    $pxs_bg2,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });
                                $pxs_prev.bind('click',function(){
                                    --current;
                                    if(current < 0)
                                        if(o.circular)
                                            current = total_elems - 1;
                                    else{
                                        ++current;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    highlight($thumbs.eq(current));
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg3,
                                    $pxs_bg2,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });

                                /*
                                clicking a thumb will slide to the respective image
                                 */
                                $thumbs.bind('click',function(){
                                    var $thumb  = $(this);
                                    highlight($thumb);
                                    //if autoplay interrupt when user clicks
                                    if(o.auto)
                                        clearInterval(slideshow);
                                    current     = $thumb.index();
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg3,
                                    $pxs_bg2,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    o.speed,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });



                                /*
                                activate the autoplay mode if
                                that option was specified
                                 */
                                if(o.auto != 0){
                                    o.circular  = true;
                                    slideshow   = setInterval(function(){
                                        $pxs_next.trigger('click');
                                    },o.auto);
                                }

                                /*
                                when resizing the window,
                                we need to recalculate the widths of the
                                slider elements, based on the new windows width.
                                we need to slide again to the current one,
                                since the left of the slider is no longer correct
                                 */
                                $(window).resize(function(){
                                    w_w = $(window).width();
                                    setWidths($pxs_slider,$elems,total_elems,$pxs_bg1,$pxs_bg2,$pxs_bg3,one_image_w,$pxs_next,$pxs_prev);
                                    slide(current,
                                    $pxs_slider,
                                    $pxs_bg3,
                                    $pxs_bg2,
                                    $pxs_bg1,
                                    1,
                                    o.easing,
                                    o.easingBg);
                                });

                            }
                        }).error(function(){
                            alert('here')
                        }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
                    });



                });
            };

            //the current windows width
            var w_w             = $(window).width();

            var slide           = function(current,
            $pxs_slider,
            $pxs_bg3,
            $pxs_bg2,
            $pxs_bg1,
            speed,
            easing,
            easingBg){
                var slide_to    = parseInt(-w_w * current);
                $pxs_slider.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to + 'px'
                },speed, easing);
                $pxs_bg3.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to/2 + 'px'
                },speed, easingBg);
                $pxs_bg2.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to/4 + 'px'
                },speed, easingBg);
                $pxs_bg1.stop().animate({
                    left    : slide_to/8 + 'px'
                },speed, easingBg);
            }

            var highlight       = function($elem){
                $elem.siblings().removeClass('selected');
                $elem.addClass('selected');
            }

            var setWidths       = function($pxs_slider,
            $elems,
            total_elems,
            $pxs_bg1,
            $pxs_bg2,
            $pxs_bg3,
            one_image_w,
            $pxs_next,
            $pxs_prev){
                /*
                the width of the slider is the windows width
                times the total number of elements in the slider
                 */
                var pxs_slider_w    = w_w * total_elems;
                $pxs_slider.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');
                //each element will have a width = windows width
                $elems.width(w_w + 'px');
                /*
                we also set the width of each bg image div.
                The value is the same calculated for the pxs_slider
                 */
                $pxs_bg1.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');
                $pxs_bg2.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');
                $pxs_bg3.width(pxs_slider_w + 'px');

                /*
                both the right and left of the
                navigation next and previous buttons will be:
                windowWidth/2 - imgWidth/2 + some margin (not to touch the image borders)
                 */
                var position_nav    = w_w/2 - one_image_w/2 + 3;
                $pxs_next.css('right', position_nav + 'px');
                $pxs_prev.css('left', position_nav + 'px');
            }

            $.fn.parallaxSlider.defaults = {
                auto            : 0,    //how many seconds to periodically slide the content.
                                        //If set to 0 then autoplay is turned off.
                speed           : 1000,//speed of each slide animation
                easing          : 'jswing',//easing effect for the slide animation
                easingBg        : 'jswing',//easing effect for the background animation
                circular        : true,//circular slider
                thumbRotation   : true//the thumbs will be randomly rotated
            };
            //easeInOutExpo,easeInBack
        })(jQuery);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For correct effect that you want to receive first of all you must change dimentions from absolute dimentions ( like px) to some scalable (like %).

You can change resolution of window and see that in some variants where buildings placed in the gaps, your script works well. See attached image.

[image: paralax effect in work]